# Content observer on mms doesn't work

Tags: android, mms, contentobserver

I need observ changes on mms content provider, so i registered content observer like this:

```
mmsObserver = new MMSObserver();
    contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms"), true, mmsObserver);
```

And just put log in onChange method in observer:

```
class MMSObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MMSObserver() {
        super(null);
    }


    public void onChange(final boolean bSelfChange) {
        super.onChange(bSelfChange);
        Timber.i("test");}}
```

But it didnt log anything, so i suppose onChange has not been called. What i did wrong, or i cannot observ content://mms, cause similar observer on content://mms-sms/conversations works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are doing anything wrong. I have encountered the same problem,  furthermore, "content://mms/part" also doesn't work.

My solution was to use the "content://mms-sms/inbox" uri and then use the "ct_t" column to determine if it was in fact an MMS.

```
String string = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex("ct_t"));
if (!"application/vnd.wap.multipart.related".equalsIgnoreCase(string) &&
    !"application/vnd.wap.multipart.mixed".equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
    // It's not an MMS
    continue;
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm testing on KitKat. Perhaps this works on other versions.